Why is Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition Unable to Create New Pull Request
In Visual Studio (Community Edition, Version 17.10.1), I am unable to create a new "Pull Request." The Create (New Pull Request) button is enabled but pressing it does nothing, there is nothing relevant in Output | Source Control - Git either.
I've setup a new Azure DevOps Server 2019 for evaluation.

My Azure DevOps organization has a project/team with a repository.
In the repository I set Branch policies on the "main" branch:

Require a minimum number of reviewers: 1.

Allow users to approve their own changes.
Allow completion even if some reviewers vote "Waiting" or "Reject".
Reset code reviewer votes when there are new changes.


Automatically include code reviewers: I added some reviewers.
I checked/changed nothing else; for now.



On my Developer workstation:

I cloned the repository locally and then created/checked-out my feature branch.
I made a trivial README.md file change and committed and pushed it.
I then checked out the "main" branch. Selected New Pull Request and filled in the dialog (Title, description, Merge into: origin/main, From: origin/<feature branch>). The Create button is enabled but, again, pressing it does nothing.

Note:

Compare Visual Studio 2022 Editions has nothing suggesting this is a limitation.
A cursory review of Microsoft Visual Studio Community License Terms indicates this research is permissible; and does not indicate limitations.


To no avail, I updated to Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.10.2.

I successfully created the New Pull Request through the Azure DevOps Server 2019 Web Portal, Repos | , Pull requests, New pull request (<feature branch> into main, Title, description, assigned reviewers), Create. A notification was sent to the reviewer and they were able to Approve, Complete/Complete merge. However, we'd prefer to not have to make developers leave their IDE (Visual Studio).

Tested to create the Pull Request with the same VS version 17.10.2, it can create the Pull Request successfully. Can you create the PR before? And can you try to clear the VS cache and re-connect the repo to create the Repo again?https://sdhruva.wordpress.com/2023/10/30/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/

On the other hand, you can check if the two branches already have a processing PR in Azure DevOps. In this case, when you click the create option in VS, it has no feedback and show warning

@KevinLu-MSFT: Thanks for your feedback. It is good to hear others are able to create the PRs. Must be something I am doing wrong, or configured wrong. Was your VS v17.10.2 the community edition, or other?

Yes. I am using the same version as yours. For  before what, I mean that use old version of vs to create PR

@KevinLu-MSFT: This works in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.9.65), against the EXACT same ADO repo and branches. Another Dev here tried it w/ VS 2022 CE and they were not presented a "New Pull Request" option; upon r-click on the checked-out main branch. I am running down your suggested "clear cache" - and considering wiping VS 2022 CE and reinstalling. I'll report back findings. We'll soon abandon this effort and (for now) live with creating PRs via the Web Portal.

Feel free to share the result with us. Then I will try to investigate the issue further.

@KevinLu-MSFT: Clear Visual Studio (VS) cash was tedious and unproductive. I might not have executed each step correctly. Ultimately, I uninstalled and then reinstalled VS. After the re-install, I experienced the same result as our other developer i.e., I am no longer presented a "New Pull Request" option; upon r-click on the checked-out main branch.
We're done with our evaluation and (for now) living with the odd issue of being unable to create the Pull Request (PR) from within VS 2022 CE IDE. We'll create the PR via the Azure DevOps (ADO) Portal.

If possible, can you share some screenshots about the error you encountered after re-installing the VS2022?

No error. There is simply no option to create a pull request. When I have some free time, I'll futz with it a bit more. Also plan to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2022. Perhaps that will change our issue/experience. I'll update this when I know more.

Will wait for your update. Thanks for your feedback.

Having the exact same issue with VS 2022 Pro against Azure DevOps Server 2019.  I strongly suspect this is a limitation (or oversight) when targeting the on-prem ADO Server. Effort seems focused on the hosted ADO Services.  We see no Create PR button and have to go to the web interface.

Upgraded our server to Azure DevOps Server 2022. No change. Neither Visual Studio 2022 nor Visual Studio 2017 community editions show a "Create PR" option when it seems they really should. Again, nothing to screen shot. There simply is no option. Again, not a show-stopper because we create the PR via the Web Portal.
